# Uv mapping an autodesk Invntor file

Tags: uv

Noob here.

I am trying to import an Autodesk inventor file into blender, unwrap the UV maps and bake the lighting into the file allowing me to place it into unity with pre-baked lights.

When I unwrap UV the image becomes stretched, Can anyone help or suggest a way around this?

Here are some examples of the Uv maps [image: Before unwrapped] [image: After unwrap]

Thanks in advance

Comment: please avoid making photos with a phone, use screengrabs. In blender use the window>save screenshot on the menu. You can then save the whole interface or the active window only.

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org Should help with better screenshots.